# Spring Boot+ Oauth 2.0 +Zuul Proxy for third party access

Tags: jquery, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am trying to create RestAPI using Spring boot + Oauth 2.0 and want to access the same from another web application.

My Spring application is deployed at localhost:8585/oauth/token.
If i use chrome REST extenstion for calling it works perfectly fine but
When i am trying to get the oauth token from my web application using jquery ajax call it gives me following error

'XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8585/oauth/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ' localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.'

I referred some documentation and @EnableZuulProxy can enable proxy for server but it didnt work

Application.class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

Web Application Page calls oauth/token with clientid , client secret and grant type as client_credential using Jquery ajax call

AND application.yml

```
zuul:
routes:
resource: 
path: oauth/*
url: http://localhost:8080/
stripPrefix: false
```

and oauth server http configuration as

.antMatchers("/oauth/token").authenticated()
    .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

Comment: You shouldn't be using client credentials grant from a browser client (it's not secure). There's a sample of a browser client and a webapp using auth code grants [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v) if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks @DaveSyer , I tried application oauth2 from the provided angular master source. Please provide source to get access_token for logged in user in ui application. Also AuthenticationPrincipal annotation is not available for method in resource server application. I have added custom user details Service with some additional params to user such as exterenal client id. How i can get them in resource Server while accessing from UI application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need an access token if you're an angular client (which is the point of the blog article). Ad far as `@AuthenticationPrincipal` is concerned, I actually don't know who is responsible for binding that, but I'd expect a method parameter that is a `Principal` to work if it's a controller you want to use it in. This is not really relevant to your original question as far as I know though, so perhaps you could pose it as another post or a github issue?